# Controller property gets cleared

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I encountered following problem :

- I call one method and inside I assign value to property id as follows

  ```
  public ActionResult WidokWydawcy(int userId)
  {
      id = userId;
      return View(id);
  }
  ```
- Then in another method I would like to take advantage of id but it turns out its value is 0, I made sure after assigning its value where diffrent.

  ```
  [ActionName("DodajAplikacjeWidok")]
  public ActionResult DodajAplikacjeWidok(string adresAplikacji)
  {
      addsEntities1 addsContext = new Models.addsEntities1();
      aplikacja app = default(aplikacja);
      if (...)
          app = App.PobierzAplikacje(adresAplikacji, id);
      return View(app);
  }
  ```

In code above id equals 0. Property definition is simple

```
private int id;
```

Marked as static it works. Can you give me a hand in grasping this?

Answer (score 0):

That is how ASP.NET MVC works. Your property value is not going to get persisted. The only way to do what you are trying to do is to have the id sent back to your second method as well.

See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127947/how-to-persist-the-data-in-memory-in-mvc-controller)

Comment: Any link with further explanation? How is that made then? Object of Controller is supposed to be created but not able to store any data?

Comment: @Maximus A controller is a controller, not a database. You'll need to find a way of persisting the value, such as passing it via query string.

Comment: @Maximus - MVC controllers behave very differently from ASP.NET WebForm's code behind. The main difference being that MVC is stateless. Now that being said you can save your value into a Session object (not the way I would do it because this technically bastardizes MVC) but it ultimately is your call

Comment: What is the proper way then you would introduce?

Comment: @Maximus, I would use models and strong typing. This way you can submit your form back to the action and have the model returned with the values you want in it. You can also call it via jQuery Ajax requests if you so choose. Again, it's up to you what path you choose.